# Android Listview Find Specific Item and select by default

Tags: android, android-listview

I would like to find a specific item in the list and have it selected by default. If I can find out the position, I can call `ListView.setItemSelected(position, true)`

I'm using a SimpleCursorAdapter to show a list of categories and this can change dynamically so I can't just find the index and hard code.

How do you find the position of a list item by a String *without* use of the OnClickListener?

Comment: I guess instead of finding in the ListView you need to find it in List or String [] which your using to populate it and find the index of the data and set the particular item as selected

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say what might be best for your implementation without seeing your code but maybe an implementation like this one

```
SimpleCursorAdapter myAdapter;
...
//search here
int count = myAdapter.getCount();
for(int i=0; i < count; i++){
    if("desired string".equals(myAdapter.getItem()){
        listView.setItemSelected(i, true);
    }
}
```